# How to Create Two Columns in Dropdown Menu

Tags: php, html, css, drop-down-menu, opencart

I want to add a second column for the items in the dropdown menu here http://www.kingadlerhomedecor.com/store/ I have a big list of items which are to be added to the category 'MEBLE' but I cannot have a really long list when there is just one column, if the list could split into two columns, i will be sorted. Please help.

```
    /* MENU */
.primary-define #menu {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: helvetica, Arial;
    /*background-color: #999;*/
}
.primary-define #menu-inner {
    position: relative;
    font-family: helvetica, Arial;
    background-color: #999; /*No color was added origninally - added to make it grey*/
}
.primary-define .mainmenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.primary-define .mainmenu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;

}
.primary-define .mainmenu > li {
    float: left;
    /*background-color: #999;*/

}
.primary-define .mainmenu li a {
    color: #666;   /*originial #666*/
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px; /*original 15px */
    padding: 0.5px 1px; /*20px 25px */ /*Padding for the dropdown elements*/
    text-decoration: none;
    /*background-color: #999;*/

}
.primary-define .mainmenu > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px 25px; /*35px*/
    font-size: 14px; /*original 18px */
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 100%;
    font-family: helvetica, Arial;

}
.primary-define .mainmenu > li:hover > a,
.primary-define .mainmenu > li.active > a {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); /*rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)*/
    /*font-size: 15px;*/
}
.primary-define .mainmenu li .dropdown-container {
    top: 99%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute; /*absolute*/
    padding-left: 1px; /*added by yuvi*/
    font-size: 30px; /*added by yuvi*/
}
.primary-define .mainmenu li .dropdown {
    margin-top: -300px; /*-999px*/
    background-color: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    font-size: 30px; /*added by yuvi*/
    padding: 10px;
}
.primary-define .mainmenu li:hover .dropdown {
    margin-top: 0;
    /*font-size: 30px; added by yuvi*/
}
}
.primary-define .mainmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    width: auto; /*249px*/
    list-style-type: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;

}
.primary-define .mainmenu ul li:hover a,
.primary-define .mainmenu ul li.active a {
    background-color: #eee; /*orginiarl #eee*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks like you would need to widen the `.dropdown` element. Currently there is an inline style of `width:300px`. I would either increase that (500px looked good to me) to make room for 2 columns or remove the inline style and add it to the stylesheet (<- recommended).

From there you can set the width of the `ul` elements to half the width of the `dropdown` and float them.

```
.primary-define .mainmenu li .dropdown ul {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none; #This is to remove the circle next to the list items
}
```

Comment: THanks Tim. It seemed to have worked. But, the circle next to the list items is still there. Is there anything else I can try to remove that?

Comment: I think, i fixed it using the store options. Thanks for your help Tim. Really appreciate your precise, detailed and clear answer.